# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) while integrating Restkit using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ipad, architecture, restkit

I am trying to integrate Restkit to my current IOS (Ipad) project. I have downloaded the rest kit sources from github (Tag:RestKit-0.22.0), and integrated the sources to my project.The sources include only the classes and not a static library/ Xcode project.

I wanted to include only the classes hence deleted the Xcode project from the downloaded sources.
I have included all the necessary frameworks in build phases section.

when I tried to build the project I am being thrown an error: **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**

```
"_RKLogCoreDataError", referenced from:

___43-[RKManagedObjectImporter finishImporting:]_block_invoke in RKManagedObjectImporter.o

___33-[RKEntityByAttributeCache load:]_block_invoke in RKEntityByAttributeCache.o

Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to Google and followed many suggestions but none helped. All the files are included under Compile Sources in build phases section.

Comment: What's the Xcode version?

Comment: edited my question with Xcode version which is 5.0.2

Comment: Why do you want to do it like that? Did you also download and install all of the dependencies?